# Python equivalent of hash_hmac in PHP

Tags: php, python

I would like to convert the following php code to python

```
"<?php echo(strtoupper(hash_hmac('SHA256', $hashinput, pack('H*',$securesecret)))); ?>"
```

and this is what l came up with

```
base64.b64encode(hmac.new(bytearray(securesecret.upper(), "ASCII") bytearray(hashInput.rstrip('&'),"ASCII") , hashlib.sha512).digest())).decode("ASCII").replace("\n", "").upper())
```

But it is not working?

Comment: Can you describe *how* it isn't working, providing examples of inputs, actual outputs and expected outputs?

Answer (score 3):

You had many syntax error in your code (forgotten commas, parenthesis incoherence, etc.). Split the code into lines, so you can develop it correctly:

```
my_secure = bytearray(securesecret.upper(), "ASCII")
my_input = bytearray(hashInput.rstrip('&'),"ASCII")
my_hmac = hmac.new(my_secure, my_input, hashlib.sha512)
my_hmac_digest = my_hmac.digest()

base64.b64encode(my_hmac_digest).decode("ASCII").upper()
```

Then you can merge it into 1 line:

```
base64.b64encode(hmac.new(bytearray(securesecret.upper(), "ASCII"), bytearray(hashInput.rstrip('&'),"ASCII"), hashlib.sha512).digest()).decode("ASCII").upper()
```

Note: using `replace("\n", "")` to remove new lines is useless, `base64.b64encode` will not split output into lines (`base64.encodestring` will)